# Fedex Shipping Label API required fields

Tags: fedex

I can't find this information anywhere in the documentation or online. I'm looking to know what are the required fields and in what circumstances they are required.

Right now I'm getting: **RequestedShipment Shipper contact - phoneNumber** is required as a response from Fedex and my problem is that I have customers that don't have a phone number or, in some cases, the formatting for the phone number is international (which also fails).

Is there any way to not make the phone number a required field when printing a fedex shipping label?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a phone number and it's required, some will enter in their own phone number so that the transaction will go thru. If it's a domestic shipment, the phone number must be 10  digits. For International I believe it must be 1-15 digits. Be sure to strip any character that is not numeric.

As far as making the number required entry, you need to handle that on your side before you send the transaction to FedEx.

Comment: You are precisely right. After a lot of digging I have found part of the doc why they require the phone number and now I have also set that field to be required on my app. The sad part is that for international numbers you need to work on the formatting so the app can accept the numbers and some special chars and the re-format for Fedex.

Comment: @Cristiano from where I can see the required fields? I am also looking for those fields

Comment: There are so many required fields, especially when doing international. The documentation states what's required but I would say much of it is going to be trial and error. I'd highly suggest you look at the sample transaction XML - these contain mostly the required fields so you should be able to reverse-engineer what is needed.

Comment: @andyknas where can I find those sample transaction XML?

Comment: On the fedex developer site you can download sample php code (and others I believe) - if you look at a sample file from the advanced download (which includes shipping) there is a file ShipWebServiceClient.php5 which sets a limited amount of data for a domestic shipment. There are other files which set data for Intl.

Comment: I found that the phone was a required field by luck. Sent a bunch of requests for them all failing. The 1st that was sent with the phone worked 100%. Setting all requests with that solved my issue. What you can do is simply var_dump the return of the request, it usually give's some information. P.S. I agree that the doc is poor.

Answer (score -2):

You can read out this ship service document:
https://www.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/201707/FedEx_WebServices_ShipService_WSDLGuide_v2017.pdf

On page number 22 you can get all the parameters, required ones are mentioned in there you have to send in a request for creating a shipping label and getting a tracking number for that shipping service. This pdf may be accessible to you only after login in your FedEx account and you can get success only if you have credentials: test account number, key, password, meter number.

When your whole request is ready if you are in testing mode try sending on:
https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship or https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services 
and if you are in production remove beta from these links.